# In react native gifted chat, how would I process a click as an ordinary message?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm referencing the code that is here:

https://snack.expo.io/@xcarpentier/gifted-chat

As the code stands, when someone press on:

```
#awesome
```

an alert will trigger due to:

```
onPress: props => alert(`press on ${props}`),
```

What I would like to do is have the press send 'Hello world' into the input as if the user had simply typed in the message and then press enter.

It seems I would need to send 'Hello world' into this function:

```
  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }));
  }
```

but I'm not sure how to do this.

How would I get the press to function like an ordinary chat input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality without needing to simulate a button press:

https://snack.expo.io/ryjHSZle7

Answer (score 2):

GiftedChat has a [`text` prop](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat#props) which controls the input text. You can use that prop to control input's text.

> If you decide to specify a `text` prop, GiftedChat will no longer manage
>   its own internal text state and will defer entirely to your prop. This
>   is great for using a tool like Redux, but there's one extra step
>   you'll need to take: simply implement `onInputTextChanged` to receive
>   typing events and reset events (e.g. to clear the text onSend)

**Sample**

```
<GiftedChat
  text={this.state.inputText}
  onInputTextChanged={text => this.setState({inputText: text})}
  /* ... */
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. So I've added this: onPress: text => this.setState({inputText: "Hello world"}) which sets the text. Is there a simple way to trigger the send command after that?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I think I am close here: https://snack.expo.io/ryp0wggxQ but when I make a final tweak here: https://snack.expo.io/HJu7_exgX I am getting an error. Any idea why?

Comment: @Hoa you didn't assign the custom button to the gifted chat like I described in my answer. `this.sendRef` is undefined

Comment: Device: (127:20) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.sendRef.props')

Comment: I've gone through line by line and everything is here: https://snack.expo.io/Hy08qegx7  but I'm still getting: Device: (134:20) undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.sendRef.props')

Comment: @Hoa mybad.. I just saw that Send component from GiftedChat does not apply the ref that we are defining. You need to create the button yourself. Just copy the contents of the button and add a ref.